# grep curly-bracketed entries from text file

Tags: bash, grep

I have a file with many curly bracketed words, ex. {test1}, {test2} - how would I `grep` for these words and output a distinct list of them?

output example:

```
{test1}
{test2}
```

I've tried this which didn't work:

```
grep -o {.*} file.xml  | sort | uniq
```

#### UPDATE

Actually - this seems to have worked:

```
grep -oP '{.*?}' file.xml | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! If you've determined your own solution you can write it up as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your first attempt. `{.*}` contains special characters which need to be protected from expansion by the shell; put quotes around the pattern. Also, `{.*}` matches the longest brace-delimited text on the line, so if you have a line containing `hello {test1} world {test2} howdy` then the output is `{test1} world {test2}` becaause `.*` matched `test1} world {test2`.

The following will output only what is between brackets.

```
grep -o -e "{[^}]*}"
```

My original formulation used "{.*}", but with that the widest bracket found within a line, not the smallest one would be returned...

Comment: Good, but why `-e`?

Comment: Just an old habit. I know, that it's optional as long as there's only one pattern.

Comment: @soulsource Can you explain this syntax? `{[^}]*}` Thanks!

Comment: The `[ ]` brackets match any character that's written between them. Followed by a `*` this matches an arbitrary number of characters from the list of characters between the `[ ]` brackets. The list of characters between the `[ ]` is in this case `^}`, meaning: "any character that's not a `}`".

Comment: Thanks! It was the `^}` I didn't understand. Thanks for the explanation!