# How can I delete all text between curly brackets in a multiline text file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, grep

Example:

```
This is {
the multiline
text file }
that wants
{ to be
changed
} anyway.
```

Should become:

```
This is 
that wants
 anyway.
```

I have found some [similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14838/sed-one-liner-to-delete-everything-between-a-pair-of-brackets) [threads](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83976/grep-curly-bracketed-entries-from-text-file) in the forum, but they don't seem to work with multi-line curly brackets.

If possible, I would prefer some one-line method, like solutions based on grep, sed, awk... etc.

EDIT: Solutions seem to be OK, but I have noticed that my original files include curly brackets nesting. So I am opening a new question. Thanks you everybody: [How can I delete all text between nested curly brackets in a multiline text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166879/how-can-i-delete-all-text-between-nested-curly-brackets-in-a-multiline-text-file)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$ sed ':again;$!N;$!b again; s/{[^}]*}//g' file
This is 
that wants
 anyway.
```

Explanation:

- `:again;$!N;$!b again;`

  This reads the whole file into the pattern space.

  `:again` is a label.  `N` reads in the next line.  `$!b again` branches back to the `again` label on the condition that this is not the last line.
- `s/{[^}]*}//g`

  This removes all expressions in braces.

On Mac OSX, try:

```
sed -e ':again' -e N -e '$!b again' -e 's/{[^}]*}//g' file
```

### Nested Braces

Let's take this as a test file with lots of nested braces:

```
a{b{c}d}e
1{2
}3{
}
5
```

Here is a modification to handle nested braces:

```
$ sed ':again;$!N;$!b again; :b; s/{[^{}]*}//g; t b' file2
ae
13
5
```

Explanation:

- `:again;$!N;$!b again`

  This is the same as before: it reads in the whole file.
- `:b`

  This defines a label `b`.
- `s/{[^{}]*}//g`

  This removes text in braces as long as the text contains no inner braces.
- `t b`

  If the above substitute command resulted in a change, jump back to label `b`.  In this way, the substitute command is repeated until all brace-groups are removed.

Answer (score 6):

Perl:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/{.*?}//sg' file
```

If you want to edit in-place

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/{.*?}//sg' file
```

That reads the file as a single string and does a global search-and-replace.

This will handle nested braced:

```
perl -ne 'do {$b++ if $_ eq "{"; print if $b==0; $b-- if $_ eq "}"} for split //'
```

Answer (score 4):

Sed:

```
sed '/{/{:1;N;s/{.*}//;T1}' multiline.file
```

started since line with `{` and get the next line (`N`) until substitution (`{}`) can be made ( `T` means return to mark made by `:` if substitution isn't made)

A little bit modify to be true if many curle bracked in one line

```
sed ':1; s/{[^}]*}// ; /{/ { /}/!N ; b1 }' multiline.file
```

Remove all symbols in the brackets (`[^}]` equal *every symbol exept `right bracket`* to make `sed` not greedy), and if in the line remain `left bracked` - back to start with next line added if there isn't `right bracket`.