# How can I delete all text between nested curly brackets in a multiline text file?

Tags: text-processing

> This question comes from
>   [How can I delete all text between curly brackets in a multiline text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166873/how-can-i-delete-all-text-between-curly-brackets-in-a-multiline-text-file) (just the same, but without the requirements for nesting).

Example:

```
This is {
{the multiline
text} file }
that wants
{ to {be
changed}
} anyway.
```

Should become:

```
This is 
that wants
 anyway.
```

Is it possible to do this with some sort of one-line bash command (awk, sed, perl, grep, cut, tr... etc)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$ sed ':again;$!N;$!b again; :b; s/{[^{}]*}//g; t b' file3
This is 
that wants
 anyway.
```

Explanation:

- `:again;$!N;$!b again`

  This reads in the whole file.

  `:again` is a label.  `N` reads in the next line and `$!N` reads in the next line on the condition that we are not already at the last line.  `$!b again` branches back to the `again` label on the condition that this is not the last line.
- `:b`

  This defines a label `b`.
- `s/{[^{}]*}//g`

  This removes text in braces as long as the text contains no inner braces.
- `t b`

  If the above substitute command resulted in a change, jump back to label `b`.  In this way, the substitute command is repeated until all brace-groups are removed.

Answer (score 3):

A Perl approach:

```
$ perl -F"" -a00ne 'for (@F){$i++ if /{/; $i||print; $i-- if /}/}' file
This is 
that wants
 anyway
```

#### Explanation

- `-a` : turns on automatic splitting on the file delimiter given by `-F` into the `@F` array.
- `-F""` : sets the input field separator to empty which will result in each element of `@F` being one of the input characters.
- `-00` : turn on "paragraph mode", where a "line" is defined as two consecutive newline characters. This means that the entire file in this case will be treated as a single line. If your file can have many paragraphs and the brackets can span multiple paragraphs, use `-0777` instead.
- `-ne` : read an input file and apply the script given by `-e` to each line.

The script itself is actually quite simple. A counter is incremented by one every time a `{` is seen and decremented by one for every `}`. This means that when the counter is 0, we are not inside brackets and should print:

- `for (@F){}` : do this for each element of `@F`, each character in the line.
- `$i++ if /{/;` : increment `$i` by one if this character is a `{`
- `$i||print;` : print unless `$i` is set (0 counts as unset).
- `$i-- if /}/` : decrement `$i` by one if this character is a `}`