# Event not found in sed call in csh script

Tags: shell, quoting, tcsh, csh

I tried the code as given on [delete text between curly brackets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166879/how-can-i-delete-all-text-between-nested-curly-brackets-in-a-multiline-text-file)

however I am facing this different error regarding event in sed.

file contains:

```
This is {
{the multiline
text} file }
that wants
{ to {be
changed}
} anyway.
```

`sed ':again;$!N;$!b again; s/{[^}]*}//g' file`

what is supposively going wrong in the workout?

Error

```
N: Event not found.
```

Comment: Was it really necessary to make a screenshot instead of providing the console content as text which the readers could copy and paste?

Comment: I provided the link and the snapshot , to state that I did exactly same. sorry for inconvenience..

many-times when i perform simple copy paste from windows to unix terminal some of *special characters* do get deleted . I don't know how.
I am using citrix based apps to run UNIX

Comment: What shell did you use?

Comment: tcsh ;
I did checked it by `echo $shell`

Comment: @JigarGandhi But now the error message is missing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to escape `!` to prevent `csh/tcsh` from performing history expansion. They still do history expansion though you wrote `!` in single quote.

Try:

```
sed ':again;$\!N;$\!b again; s/{[^}]*}//g' file
```

Or you can write a script an call with `-f script.sed` (Read [sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq5.html#s5.11)).

Comment: You can also disable history expansion with `set histchars`. The `histchars` variable contains which characters to use for history expansion (you can reset this to the default with `set histchars = "!^"`).

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with `tcsh` but this sounds like a history expansion problem. In `bash` single quotes prevent history expansion, maybe in `tcsh` they don't.

You may disable history expansion (I don't know how to do that, though; in `bash` this is done by `set +H`).

Another option: Backslash escapes should work. Try

```
sed_code=":again;\$\!N;\$\!b again; s/{[^}]*}//g"
sed "$sed_code" file
```

Comment: I am unable to assign `sed_code=":again;\$\!N;\$\!b again; s/{[^}]*}//g"` as the variable is not assigned.

here is one article regarding it. [variable trouble](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt)

Comment: @JigarGandhi This is how it would be done in `bash`. You have to translate it to `tcsh` code yourself (or wait for someone who is familiar with it).

Comment: It seems to be a law that every (t)csh question has at least one answer from a (knowledgeable) bash/zsh user, with an answer that doesn't apply to tcsh, or doesn't work...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker But you do realize, I hope, that my answer was the first, identified the problem correctly, and pointed at the correct solution. It would be ridiculous to suggest this answer had better not been given.

Comment: It doesn't point to a correct solution, since `set +H` doesn't work in `tcsh`, and neither does `sed_code=":again;\$\!N;\$\!b again; s/{[^}]*}//g"`. You did make a good estimate as to the problem, but IMHO this is not enough to qualify as a decent answer.