# Replace certain text occurred within curly brackets

Tags: text-processing, sed, tcsh

I have sample file as follow :

```
 WEA {
     Direction = Input
     Tag = WriteEnable
     PortId = "A"
 }
 MEA {
     Direction = Input
     Tag = MemoryEnable
     PortId = "A"
 }
 CLKA {
     Direction = Input
     Tag = Clock
     PortId = "A"
 }
 TEST1A {
     Direction = Input
     Tag = None
     TieLevel = TestBench
     PortId = "A"
     SafeValue = "1'b0"
 }
```

I am trying to replace `PortId = "A"` as `PortId = "A B"` but in only the `CLKA{ }` module.

I tried to run certain modification on code given as

```
sed ':again;$\!N;$\!b again; s/{[^}]*}//g' file
```

on previous post [remove text within curly brackets](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170804/event-not-found-in-sed/170814?noredirect=1#170814)

I tried this `sed ':again;$\!N;$\!b again; s/CLKA {[^}]*}//g'` but deleted whole `CLKA { }` module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```bsh
sed '/CLKA/,/TEST1A/ { s/PortId = \"A/& B/; }' file
```

This sed command appends the `B` character to the end of pattern `PortId = "A` which is between two words `CLKA` and `TEST1A`.

Also you can use start(`^`) and end(`$`) of line notifies to match/replace only `PortId = "A"` inside the `CLKA { ... }` module. `^ CLKA {$` matches the line which only contains  `CLKA {` and `^ }$` matches the line if only contains  `}`

#### Input:

```
CLKA {
     PortId = "A"
}

 CLKA {    
     Direction = Input
     Tag = Clock
     PortId = "A"
 }
```

#### Command:

```bsh
sed '/^ CLKA {$/,/^ }$/ { s/PortId = \"A/& B/; }' file
```

#### Output:

```
CLKA {
     PortId = "A"
}

 CLKA {    
     Direction = Input
     Tag = Clock
     PortId = "A B"
 }
```

Note that spaces after `^` because you have a space before each lines(in your given example), if you don't have this space, remove them.

Comment: Can I use same for `append` function too?
`sed -i '/start_pattern/,/end_patter/ { /replace_mark/ a <text_line_to_be_added> } ' <file.txt>`