# sed to append at specific line within certain limit only

Tags: shell-script, sed, tcsh

I want to append a particular text after match of the particular line only.

Currently, in example one can see I added the line `rpmos xi92`; can I use append switch in `sed` as per this [workout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170979/replace-certain-text-occurred-within-curly-brackets)

### Sample_text

```
module sac1 ( out_ports , in_ports );
    output out_ports;
    input in_ports;
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi92 ( net307, rdb, rblt, vnwa );
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi82 ( vddai, sel_b, net287, vnwa );
endmodule

module sac2 ( out_ports , in_ports );
    output out_ports;
    input in_ports;
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi92 ( net307, rdb, rblt, vnwa );
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi82 ( vddai, sel_b, net287, vnwa );
endmodule
```

### Command

```
sed -i '/module sac1/ , /endmodule/ {/pmos_bulk_vt3  xi92/a rpmos   xi92 \( net307\, rblt\, rdb \)\;}'
```

### Desired_text

```
module sac1 ( out_ports , in_ports );
    output out_ports;
    input in_ports;
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi92 ( net307, rdb, rblt, vnwa );
    rpmos  xi92 (net307, rblt, rdb );
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi82 ( vddai, sel_b, net287, vnwa );
endmodule

module sac2 ( out_ports , in_ports );
    output out_ports;
    input in_ports;
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi92 ( net307, rdb, rblt, vnwa );
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi82 ( vddai, sel_b, net287, vnwa );
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all characters after `a` command is treated as string to be appended, hence `sed` will complain about `` unmatched `{' ``

One way is to use `-e` (tested with `GNU sed`, not sure about portability)

```
$ sed -e '/module sac1/ , /endmodule/ {/pmos_bulk_vt3  xi92/a\    rpmos   xi92 (net307, rblt, rdb );' -e '}' ip.txt    
module sac1 ( out_ports , in_ports );
    output out_ports;
    input in_ports;
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi92 ( net307, rdb, rblt, vnwa );
    rpmos   xi92 (net307, rblt, rdb );
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi82 ( vddai, sel_b, net287, vnwa );
endmodule

module sac2 ( out_ports , in_ports );
    output out_ports;
    input in_ports;
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi92 ( net307, rdb, rblt, vnwa );
    pmos_bulk_vt3  xi82 ( vddai, sel_b, net287, vnwa );
endmodule
```

- Note that `\` is not needed to escape characters like `(` in replacement section

Or you can also use

```
$ sed '/module sac1/ , /endmodule/ {/pmos_bulk_vt3  xi92/a\    rpmos   xi92 (net307, rblt, rdb );
}' ip.txt
```

- press enter after end of `a` command and then add rest of command
- See also [GNU sed manual - Multiple commands syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Multiple-commands-syntax)