# Simple if command not working in csh script

Tags: shell-script, csh

Problem is that when I execute this script using `source overspeed` (after giving myself execute permission), it asks me "How fast are you going?" as what I set but after I enter any value it gives an error "Event not found" instead of displaying "You are over speeding!!!".

**Here is my script by the way:**

```
#!/bin/csh
# Over speed indicator
#
echo -n "How fast are you going?"
set speed = $<
if (speed > 100) echo "You are over speeding!!!"
```

Comment: I'll be one of the first to suggest that your shell script education may be better served learning anything other than csh or tcsh.

Comment: In this case, the `!!!` in your string are likely being interpreted as history expansion commands: see [Event not found in sed call in csh script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170804/event-not-found-in-sed-call-in-csh-script)

Comment: @steeldriver I have even removed that "!!!" from my syntax now it is giving an error "if: Expression syntax"

Comment: you probably mean `($speed >100)`.

Comment: Output of `echo $SHELL` please

Comment: @michas I even set it to `($speed >100)` then also it is showing error "if: Expression syntax"

Comment: @roaima I told in question that the output of my script is basically error "Event not found"

Comment: @roaima I am sorry I misinterpreted your question. It is giving `/usr/bin/csh` as an output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of mistakes in your script. The first line should point to your `csh` executable, which you've identified in the comments as `/usr/bin/csh` (rather than `/bin/csh`). The `if` line is missing the `$` to identify `speed` as a variable. Here is a corrected script

```
#!/usr/bin/csh
# Over speed indicator
#
echo -n "How fast are you going?"
set speed = $<
if ($speed > 100) echo "You are over speeding\!\!\!"
```

Ideally you would then run it as `./overspeed` rather than `source overspeed` so that any variables it sets are retained in its own context rather than polluting your interactive shell.

Better than all of this, stop trying to learn a shell language that's fundamentally broken for scripting, and use one of the `sh` variants instead (`ksh` or `bash`). Here is your script rewritten to use `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Over speed indicator
#
read -p "How fast are you going? " speed
if $(( speed > 100 ))
then
    echo 'You are over speeding!!!'
fi
```

As before, if the script file is executable you can run it with `./overspeed`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @roaima you cleared a lot of my concepts. Just one question that `./overspeed` doesn't work. It says command not found.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(( $speed > 100 ))` or even `(( speed < 100 ))` for numeric comparison? [When used with [[, the ‘<’ and ‘>’ operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs)

Comment: @Ninja `chmod +x overspeed`

Comment: @Jeff Schaller permission was already set but it didn't work. Its ok thanks

Comment: I found the answer why I was not been able to execute the script using `./overspeed`. It's because I wrote "usr" while writing directory path in the first line as told by @roaima. If I do only `#!/bin/csh` then I can execute the script using './overspeed' without any problem.

Comment: @Ninja the reason I changed the first line is because your SHELL declared itself so. If you've got a working line now that's good

Comment: @steeldriver oops, yes. I was mixing and matching between languages. Usually I'd have gone with `test $x -gt $y` type syntax but with your reminder I've stayed with `$(( x > y ))` this time. Thank you